# How can I position a modal box out of the browser in HTML?

Tags: html, css, browser, popup, css-position

I want to position a modal box (position: absolute) out of browser, but I can't get it work.

It would be cool to position modal box on secondary monitor (if user has one, of course).

Hey, this one keeps me frustrating :/

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you say you can't get it to work we need to know what you've already tried.

Comment: I tried to set a negative offset. I also tried those fancy JAVASCRIPTs but dunno whats wrong with them.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this. Just about the only way to display content outside of the browser window area is with the Javascript window.open() method, though note that this method will probably be blocked by the user's popup blocker unless it's triggered by a user action (like clicking a link).

Comment: It must be a HTML modal box not a popup window. (Because of style and stuff...). Maybe there are some CSS tricks that could make it possible ?

Comment: There is no was CSS can target anything outside of the window.